# Erro ao fazer upload de ficheiros

Tags: php, javascript, html

Pretendo fazer upload de ficheiros, onde insiro o nome do ficheiro em base de dados e o ficheiro numa pasta no servidor.

Estou a tentar desta forma:

HTML:

```
<form class="form5" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row clearfix">
<span class="btn fileinput-button">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
<span>Add Arquivo...</span>
<input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo">
</span>
</div>
</form>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="mensagem-sucesso" onclick="inserir_anexos()">Gravar</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function inserir_anexos()
{  
    var dadosajax = {
        'CodigoUtente' : $("#CodigoUtente6").val(),
        'arquivo' : $("#arquivo").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './recebe_upload',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
            Swal.fire("Erro!", "Tente novamente. Caso persista o erro, contatar Administrador!", "error");
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
            $('.form5')[0].reset();
            Swal.fire('Boa!', 'Gravado com sucesso!', 'success');
        }
    });
}
```

o PHP tenho desta forma:

```
$CodigoUtente = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["CodigoUtente"]);
$Colaborador = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];
$pathToSave = "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/sparkling/alimentacao";

if (!file_exists($pathToSave)) {
    mkdir("$pathToSave", 0777);
}

   if ($_POST['arquivo']) { 
        $dir = $pathToSave; 
        $tmpName = $_POST['arquivo']['tmp_name']; 

        $name = $_POST['arquivo']['name'];
        preg_match_all('/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $name, $extensao);
        if (!in_array(strtolower(current(end($extensao))), array('.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.xls', '.xlms'))) {
            echo('Permitido apenas arquivos doc,xls,pdf e txt.');
           
            die;
        }

       if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $dir.$name)) { 
            echo('Arquivo adicionado com sucesso.');
        } else {
            echo('Erro ao adicionar arquivo.');
        }   


           $query = 'INSERT INTO raddb.UploadArquivo(CodigoUtente, arquivo, Colaborador)  
           VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)';
           $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
           $stmt->bind_param("sss", $CodigoUtente, $name, $Colaborador);
           $stmt->execute();    
    }
```

Mas quando faço gravar recebo esta mensagem na consola:

> Permitido apenas arquivos doc,xls,pdf e txt.

E estou a fazer insert de um pdsf como mostro na imgem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E na consola do browser o nome do ficheiro também é enviado, como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas nem insere na base de dados nem guarda o ficheiro pdf na pasta indicado.

Podem ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

*"nem insere na base de dados nem guarda o ficheiro pdf na pasta indicado"*
Sim, por causa do `die` ele para o processamento e não insere. Essa validação pode ser mais simples, tente assim no lugar do `preg_match_all` e um `regex`:

```
$permitidos = array('txt', 'pdf', 'doc', 'xls', 'xlms');
$name = $_POST['arquivo']['name'];
$extensao = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($extensao, $permitidos)) {
    echo('Permitido apenas arquivos doc,xls,pdf e txt.');

    die;
}
```

Comment: alterei essa parte do código, mas continua a parar o processamento no die

Comment: sim, mas isso é esperado correcto? se a extensão não for permitida deve parar ai, senão vai inserir um arquivo inválido. Se fizer upload de um arquivo com extensão válida funciona? No na minha resposta o nome do input estava errado, veja se está testando com esse código que está agora pf

Comment: estou a fazer upload de um arquivo com a extensão pdf, é uma extensão válida, mas o processamento para sempre no die.

Comment: @RicardoPontual, `pathinfo()` retorna a extensão do arquivo sem o ponto o que faz co o que sempre caia dentro do 'if'

Comment: tem razão @AugustoVasques, testei aqui e estava com esse problema... copiei esse codigo de uma pagina aqui, mas colei o array que estava na pergunta e não me atentei nisso, vou atualizar a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Está dando erro porque `$_POST['arquivo']` retorna uma string obtida com o elemento `<input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo">` e quando faz...

- `$tmpName = $_POST['arquivo']['tmp_name'];`
- `$name = $_POST['arquivo']['name'];`

...tanto `$tmpName` e `$name` são indefinidos.

```
if ($_POST['arquivo']) { 
        $dir = $pathToSave; 
        $name = $_POST['arquivo'];
        // Não estou certo que temp seja uma pasta do cliente, acredito que deva ser o endereço de uma pasta dentro do servido mas a pergunta não deixa claro.
        $tmpName = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

        // PATHINFO_EXTENSION retorna a extensão sem o ponto
        $extensao = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (!in_array($extensao, ['txt', 'pdf', 'doc', 'xls', 'xlms'])) {
            echo('Permitido apenas arquivos doc,xls,pdf e txt.');

            die;
        }

        // continue com o seu código a partir desse ponto
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema estava ao enviar os dados no `ajax`. Para resolver o meu problema, alterei o `js`.
Assim a variável `arquivo` já não é enviada como `string`, mas sim como `file`

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $(".form5").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         url: "./recebe_upload",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
   beforeSend : function()
   {
    //$("#preview").fadeOut();
    $("#err").fadeOut();
   },
   success: function(data)
      {
    if(data=='invalid')
    {
     // invalid file format.
     $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
     // view uploaded file.
     $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
     $("#arquivo").val(""); 
     $("#dataModal5").modal("hide");     
    }
      },
     error: function(e) 
      {
    $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
      }          
    });
 }));
});
```

e no php ficou desta forma:

```
$codigo = $_POST['CodUtente'];
$Colaborador = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];

$pathToSave = "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/sparkling/arquivo_psicologia/";

if (!file_exists($pathToSave)) {
    mkdir("$pathToSave", 0777);
}
if ($_FILES) {
   if ($_FILES['arquivo']) { 
        $dir = $pathToSave; 
        $tmpName = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']; 

        $name = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
        preg_match_all('/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $name, $extensao);
        if (!in_array(strtolower(current(end($extensao))), array('.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.xls', '.xlms'))) {
            echo('Permitido apenas arquivos doc,xls,pdf e txt.');

            die;
        }

       if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $dir.$name)) { 
            echo('Arquivo adicionado com sucesso.');
        } else {
            echo('Erro ao adicionar arquivo.');
        }   


           $query = 'INSERT INTO raddb.UploadArquivo(CodigoUtente, arquivo, Colaborador)  
           VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)';
           $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
           $stmt->bind_param("sss", $codigo, $name, $Colaborador);
           $stmt->execute();    
    }
}
```